# IOS 7.1.2 and Xcode 5.1 PushNotifications for new app not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, xcode5.1

i developed a new app after updating to xcode 5.1. i have made many apps on previous versions and all of them receiving pushnotifications properly but my new app which i develop on xcode 5.1 and on my iphone 5s iOS 7.1.2 not receiving push notifications. i coded like i did with other apps before but this one is not receiving PN. Is anyone else having this issue?? or is there any solution?? or is it just a IOS or XCODE error??

i followed this tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: Share the code of your implementation for push notification..

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
  (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

Comment: and didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken and didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError

Comment: so did you receive your device id ?

Comment: just go and change on your plist that receive notification on background also it will work

Comment: yes i did receive device token and then i used it in php for sending pn as i were doing with my previous apps but i did not receive any notification for this app.

Comment: Then there are chances that there is a bundle id mismatch ?

Comment: @Mohit yes i did that but no difference. Thanks

Comment: @NKB No chance :) thanks

Comment: no All the bundle ids are same for this app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving the push notification device id. There are chances that there can be a mismatch in the bundle id. Kindly consider checking it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Pem file and its private key Consider recreating the certificates and the profile, if you have already checked everything then try testing with help of simplepush.php file which is found in the tutorial you have mentioned, check if you get PN after replacing device token and pen file, if you do, then Its surely a problem from your server